Infinite integral of the Fourier transform of arbitrary function related to the time domain.
I have some arbitrary function $x(t)$ and its Fourier transform, $\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} = X(\omega)$. I'm trying to understand the meaning of the integral of $X(\omega)$.
By Parseval's theorem we know that
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x(t)|^2 dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |X(\omega)|^2 d\omega $
But what is
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) d\omega$ ?
How would I solve this, by some change of variables?

Using the Fourier Inverse Transform the result is $2\pi f(0)$

So - equal to zero?

No. It's equal to $2\pi x(0)$.  That is $x(t)$ evaluated at $t=0$.  Invoke the Inverse theorem

Recall that if $x(t)$ has a Fourier Transform $X(\omega)$, and $X(\omega)\in L^1$, then
$$x(t)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\tag1$$
Now, set $t=0$ in $(1)$.  Can you finish?

@user70478 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.
